# Exclude line of code from being compiled without ts-ignore

Tags: typescript, eslint

I use ESLint with Angular v13.

I got the following lint error while using `// @ts-ignore`:

```
Do not use "// @ts-ignore" comments because they suppress compilation errors @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
```

Seems `@typescript-eslint` doesn't recommend the use of `@ts-ignore`.

Is there any alternative way to tell the TypeScript compiler to ignore a specific line from the code?

Comment: Why do you need to tell the compiler to ignore that line? If you really _must_, then you need to tell ESLint to ignore the rule (for that line, at least).

Comment: or type your line with any types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the rule `@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment` to allow a `@ts-ignore` comment when it comes with a description. More info [here](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-ts-comment#allow-with-description).

1. In your code, add a description to your `@ts-ignore` comment:

```
//@ts-ignore: describe why you're using ts-ignore here
...code...
```

2. In your ESLint configuration file (`eslintrc.*`), configure the rule accordingly:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": [
      "error",
      {
        "ts-ignore": "allow-with-description"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```